# async components - can't see the loader and the actual component

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js

i have 2 components:

- `hello.vue` - actual component i want to render
- `loader.vue` - component that contains a loader

i have written `app.vue` (code below) to load `hello.vue` asynchronously (using the delay property).

actual behavior is that nothing is shown.
if i try to render the `loader.vue` component and `hello.vue` separately, they are working.

the whole code [can be found on here](https://github.com/iliran11/vue-js-async-component)

so how to get the following behavior:
1.loader of `loader.vue` is seen for 200ms
2. `hello.vue` is replacing it.

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <AsyncComp></AsyncComp>
</template>

<script>
const hello = () => import('./hello.vue')
import loader from './loader.vue'
const AsyncComp = () => ({
  // The component to load. Should be a Promise
  component: hello,
  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: loader,
  delay: 200
})
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: { hello, loader, AsyncComp }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you should use kebab-case for your HTML tags.

Comment: Also, see [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)